# Left side of profile page is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, layout

It appears the profile page is not placing the content within the correct boundaries.  The whole left side is off a few pixels.  I don't know if it's just the contents completely shifted to the left (I notice a big gap on the right between the horizontal dividers and the right boundary) or the gap really belongs on both sides.

[image: the gap]

It only appears here on Gaming (the main site and meta) and doesn't appear on other sites so I think there's some bugs in the site's CSS files.

It is like this on both FF8 and IE9 on Win7x64.

Comment: Repro here on Chrome 15.0.874.121

Comment: Same here on Chrome 16.0.912.41 beta-m

Comment: Repro on FF6.0.2 on 64-bit Vista.

Comment: Me too!  Firefox 7.0.1, Ubuntu.

Comment: I get this on the meta site, but everything seems to be in order on the main site.  Chrome 15.0.874.121.   See [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3338/background-bullying-me-on-my-meta-profile).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have rolled out on the per-site metas yet.

Comment: Looks like it's finally out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113840/150562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new profile pages finally being deployed now, this looks like it won't be an issue now.  This was only an issue with the older profile pages.  It will only be a matter of time until it gets deployed on meta and network-wide.

[image: new profile page]